# Rails: local workstation parses time differently than server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone-offset

Have some code to parse a string w/ time zone:

```
Time.strptime("5/28/19 14:26:36 Eastern Time (US & Canada)", '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S %Z')
```

The weird thing is that on my local machine, the result is: `2019-05-28 14:26:36 -0600`.

However when I run the same line on my Heroku staging server, the result is `2019-05-28 14:26:36 +0000`.

Perhaps there is some system/Rails time zone configuration that differs between the two environments, but I would expect them to parse the same string correctly.

Using the same version of Ruby, Rails, and all gems on both environments.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The Ruby Time class is not timezone aware and will use the system time. You can use `Time.zone.strptime("5/28/19 14:26:36 Eastern Time (US & Canada)", '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S %Z')` to use [`ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html) which is timezone aware. [Thoughbot has a really good intro this nightmare inducing subject](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/its-about-time-zones).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `Time.zone.strptime` to take the timezone into consideration like

```
Time.zone.strptime("5/28/19 14:26:36 Eastern Time (US & Canada)", '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S %Z')
```

Comment: Ohh ok let me try that out. Thanks.

Comment: Ok that seemed to work, thanks!